# Listing all fixity declarations in Quasiquote monad

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, quasiquotes

I would like to list all fixity declarations in Quasiquote monad so I am able to pass all the infix operators from Haskell grammar to my Quasiquote grammar.

Is there any method in `template-haskell` which allows me to do so please? I can't find any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I have found the related [issue](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/4430) in GHC Gitlab.

The problem can't have any solution because the compilation logic can't allow that. For example, there might be two templates, both of which make a new fixity declaration and therefore if both of them are trying to list them all, they might end in an endless loop.

If the only reason, why do I want to get all fixity declarations is parsing infix operators to be later used by Haskell, the usage of `UInfixE Exp Exp Exp` is recommended.

The arbitrary tree created using the `UInfixE` is later processed by Haskell compiler to the correct `"InfixE"` tree, so the expression is correctly processed with all the fixity declarations.

Syntax careless and type ignoring example:
`UInfixE 1 * (UnfixE 2 + 3)` passed by a template gets transformed in later phase of compilation, when all fixity declarations are known, to `InfixE (InfixE 1 * 2) + 3`